# How to confirm several TCP connections come from one computer?

Tags: node.js, tcp

I have a C/S model that each client use 3 or more TCP connections to one Server, for example one connection for binary data, one for text messages and one for controlling.

However, I have no idea how to "group" these 3 connections as one client.

I've tried use IP to identical, but different client may have same IP address.

Though I'm using node.js, I think this is a common problem may appear in any languages/implements.

Comment: One very trivial way is to have the client send a GUID when it connect. The client should send the same GUID for every connection in that "connection session".

Comment: I think this is the way to go, just like cookies.

Comment: Well, it's *a* way. It has some flaws (i.e. security implications), but for a trivial assignment, why not? :D The approach is also usable with protocols like HTTP if custom data can be sent. Although, I've usually found that it's easier to handle a *single* stream per client. FTP was/is .. FTP. *Uck*.

Comment: The question is about TCP connections.  Not HTTP connections.  Cookies are an HTTP implementation.

Comment: @Daniel The same concept holds: the client transmits a unique ID that only it should have. Cookies or custom headers (or abused headers) could be used with HTTP. Of course there is no such TCP header for such a value, so a protocol on top of TCP (like HTTP) would have to account for it.

Comment: Yes, it requires a concept similar to cookies, but again, the question is TCP, not HTTP.

Comment: @Daniel It's not about TCP at all. That's just a bum tag. It's about a protocol on top of TCP (custom or otherwise). If there is no protocol, then there is no data sent and we have no assignment to worry about.

Comment: @user2246674 You're assuming it's a "bum tag".  Clearly the poster responded to you with "just like cookies".  So I think it's safe to say the poster isn't using HTTP.

Comment: @Daniel HTTP cookies were an example. Take it or leave it. I suggest leaving it, if it's that much of a step. 1. **"the same concept holds"** and; 2. **"it's about a protocol on top of TCP"**.

Comment: @Daniel Come on, no argument on this.

Comment: @user2246674 Single stream may block, that's why I decide to have multiple streams. Anyway, this is about my own protocol on top of TCP, IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you can do is handle it at an application layer.  Send some data that the clients have to return to you in some form for each connection.  (Look at the SSL handshaking process.  Maybe just use that!)